# Not getting notifications in receiver side

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am using two firebase database projects. I have to send notifications from one database(Project-A) to another database(Project-B). I am sending notifications through API calls in cloud functions( in Project-A) and have to receive in IOS device ( from Project-B). I am sending the device token which is generated by using Project-A's SenderId through  API call and saving that token in Project-A's database. In Project-A, using cloud function I am sending a notification to the IOS device in Project-B. In Project-A's firebase console it showing the notification is successfully sent, but in the receiver side, I am not getting any notification.

Payload:

```
 let payload = {

    notification: {
        title: "Notification Alert",
        body:  "Notification Body",
        sound: "default",
    },
    'data':{// these is the data it calls in the messagereceived method
       'SenderID':senderauthid,
       'ReceiverId':receiverauthid,
       'SenderPhoneNumber':String(senderphonenumber),
       'SenderName':Sendertotalname,
       'flag':"3",
    }

 };//payload

 return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(RegisterationTokens, payload).then((response)=> { 

    console.info("Successfully sent notification")
    return res.status(200).json({Token : "Successfully sent notification"});

 }).catch(function(error) {
    console.warn("Error sending notification " , error)
 });//end of notification
```

On successful notification message sent, I am receiving an error message stating that

```
errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/invalid-apns-credentials',
     message: 'A message targeted to an iOS device could not be sent because the required APNs SSL certificate was not uploaded or has expired. Check the validity of your development and production certificates.' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
```

I have already added "APNs Auth Keys" in "APNs Authentication Key" section in firebase console. Do I have to make any changes?

Comment: Can you share the payload which you are creating for the notification also check if the apns key is added in the firebase project.

Comment: I have added the APNs Auth Keys in both projects.

Comment: In your firebase console, Go to **Settings -> CloudMessaging** in your firebase console. There will be one section iOS app configuration. There you need to set the APNs authentication key